# Show that $x = \sqrt{ab}$ in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: If $ABCD$ is a square and $BC$ is a diameter.

> Show that  $x = \sqrt{ab}$.

[image]

Progress:
Let $h$  = height $\triangle TPQ$

$$\triangle TPQ \sim \triangle TAD$$$$
\frac{h+a+b+x}{h} = \frac {a+b+x}{x} \iff \frac{a+b + x}{h} = \frac{a+b}x$$

....?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but take a look: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/GeometricMean.shtml at least the $\sqrt{ab}$ screams geometric mean to me

Comment: This looks helpful perhaps? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz12r.png

Comment: Maybe an initial sentence is necessary : "Let $T$ be given on the semi-circle, and lengths $a,b,x$  defined by $BP, PQ,QC$ resp". [At first, I had understood wrongly that lengths $a,b$ were given beforehand]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting $l=a+b+x$ your result can be written as:
$$
{l\over h}={l-x\over x},
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
h={lx\over l-x}.
$$
On the other hand, in right triangle $BCT$ we have:
$$
h^2=(a+x_1)(b+x_2),
$$
where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the projections of $PT$ and $QT$ on $BC$.
But $x_1=ah/l$, $x_2=bh/l$, which inserted into previous formula give:
$$
h^2=ab\left(1+{h\over l}\right)^2.
$$
Substituting here $h={lx\over l-x}$ we get $x^2=ab$.

Comment: Many compliments.

Comment: Can explain $x_1=\frac{ah}{l}$

Comment: @petaarantes By similar triangles: $PH:HT=PB:BA$, where $H$ is the projection of $T$ on $BC$.

Comment: thanks..now I see